# What columns get searched in Sonata-Admin global search

Tags: php, symfony, sonata-admin

The global search option in Sonata Admin searches trough all the (doctrine2) entities that have Admin Classes associated with them.

What I am trying to figure out is how to configure what columns get searched by the global search. In my clients website it seems to be searching trough all VARCHAR fields (doctrine type: string) and not the TEXT fields (doctrine type: text).

Does anybody know why this is, and how it can be changed?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

According to sonata admin's documentation they have mentioned that global search module will search for all visible admins i.e `show_in_dashboard` is set to true, and it will search in only those fields which are in configured admin's `configureDatagridFilters()` function only,So the fields added to `$datagridMapper` object of admin class will be searched in Sonata admin's global search.

For example you have news admin and  in `configureListFields()` you have 3 fields

```
protected function configureListFields(ListMapper $listMapper)
{
    $listMapper
        ->addIdentifier('id')
        ->add('name')
        ->add('createdDate');
}
```

And in `configureDatagridFilters()` you have only name field to filter results

```
protected function configureDatagridFilters(DatagridMapper $datagridMapper)
{
    $datagridMapper->add('name');
}
```

So Sonata will search in only name field of your news admin because you have configured a filter for this admin,So this filter is also used in global search for admin and no other field will be searched except name field

---

According to docs

> The "global search" allows the end user to iterate over all visible
>   admins in the dashboard and search for the keyword. The current
>   implementation is very simple, every filter related to a string will
>   be searchable by default.

[`ADMIN BUNDLE ~ GLOBAL SEARCH`](http://sonata-project.org/blog/2013/10/1/admin-bundle-global-search)

---

Other information regarding sonata global search is

> The search iterates over admin classes and look for filter with the
>   option global_search set to true. If you are using the
>   SonataDoctrineORMBundle any text filter will be set to true by
>   default.

By default sonata looks for field description if set to string it automatically involves in global search you can also force field to be used in search by setting field option in `$datagridMapper`'s `add()`like below

```
->add('name', null, array('global_search' => true), null, array()
```

[`Sonata Search`](http://sonata-project.org/bundles/admin/master/doc/reference/search.html)

Comment: Thanks for your quick and detailed reply M Khalid Junaid, it does not help me (yet) however, because it seems like Sonata uses more to determine on what columns to search. 

I want sonata to search in the comment field in the Comment entity, and I have added this field to the dataGridFilters in CommentAdmin:

`protected function configureDatagridFilters(DatagridMapper $datagridMapper)
    {
        $datagridMapper
            ->add('user')
            ->add('comment')
`

In my results however, I simply get ALL the comments (no filtering)

Comment: M Khalid Jnaid, your answer did help me in the right direction, I got it working with the following line:
`->add('comment', null, array('global_search' => true), null, array())`
(so "options" is probably the third argument instead of the fifth). can you update your answer so I can approve it (so other people might have a use for this topic).

Comment: @vitrus Glad it help you i have updated my answer please have a look